# How do I test keyboard shortcuts (globalShortcut)?

Tags: node.js, electron, integration-testing, spectron, robotjs

I want to write integration tests for global keyboard shortcuts in electron.

My app has some webviews with the functionality of zoom in/out to be tested using `cmd=` and `cmd-` keys respectively.

I have tried several testing frameworks like spectron, robotJS, node-key-sender. Nothing seems to work. The problem being the `cmd` key is not recognized as a keyboard input.

Any pointers on this?